# How to disable autogrowing of the field in JEditable?

Tags: jeditable

I have been developing the application and I use the following code for JEditable:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
        $(function() 
        {  
             $(".field").editable("http://"+document.location.host+"/index.php/welcome/update_record", 
             { 
                event  : "mouseover",
                style  : "inherit",
                autogrow: {
                    lineHeight : 0,
                    maxHeight : 0
                },
                submitdata: function (value, settings) {
                            return { "old_value": this.revert};
                },
                callback: function(value, settings) 
                {
                }
            });  
        });
```

I need to disable autogrowing of the field in order to if user moves on a fields then the field won't grow. Now field grows if user moves on it. I need it, please help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I have used with success

width     : '100%' as a parameter. Give it a try.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
        $(function() 
        {  
             $(".field").editable("http://"+document.location.host+"/index.php/welcome/update_record", 
             { 
                event  : "mouseover",
                width     : '100%'
                style  : "inherit",
                autogrow: {
                    lineHeight : 0,
                    maxHeight : 0
                },
                submitdata: function (value, settings) {
                            return { "old_value": this.revert};
                },
                callback: function(value, settings) 
                {
                }
            });  
        });
```